# R padding time series with grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have **data frame with columns** action, type, **project_id, week, events_in_time**

I want to run some analysis on each subgroup defined by action, type. 
Currently I have a problem with padding time series (column week). For some projects I don't have any entry for given week.

**How can I add 0 values in events_in_time for missing weeks in all projects?**

I tried merging as described here: https://bocoup.com/weblog/padding-time-series-with-r by generating all weeks and merging it but nothing happens. I understand that I would need probably to generate this for all projects but I can't find how to do it.
what i did:

```
all.week.frame=data.frame(week=seq(0,12)) # i now it only fills first 12 weeks
merged=merge(data, all.week.frame, all=T)
```

example data:
http://pastebin.com/au3EfbGA

save to file and load with

```
data= read.table("merged.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

**update**:
I found that using

```
complete(data_filtered, nesting(type,action, project_id), week, fill = list(events_in_time = 0))
```

solves it

Comment: share a sample data for us to work on!

Comment: added example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `complete` from `tidyr` is what you are looking for.
It takes a data.frame, followed by columns to complete (things to make sure all match up), then a list of what values to insert if the combination is missing. Here, it takes `df`, makes all combinations of `week` and `project_id`, then fills your only other column (`events_in_time`) with `0` whenever there is no entry.

```
complete(df, week, project_id, fill = list(events_in_time = 0))
```